# Adding pyspark python path in oozie

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, oozie

I'm trying to run a simple python script on Oozie using Hue. I'm using anaconda parcels installed so I've also add in Cloudera manager, spark configuration (Spark Service Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for spark-conf/spark-env.sh)

```
if [ -z "${PYSPARK_PYTHON}" ]; then
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python
fi
```

When running the job, i've a python error
ImportError: No module named pandas.io.json
, meaning that the PYSPARK_PYTHON doesn't seems to take the one from anaconda.

I've tried to add an arguments with

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python
```

on the spark action via hue, but doesn't seems to work.

If I run the scripts via CLI and spark-submit it works.
If I run other python scripts on Oozie via Hue (without packages from anaconda) it works.

What am I missing ? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using spark via Oozie you need to tell what environment variables should be set on launcher container (the one that starts spark session).

Try adding a new property of spark action with key `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.env` and value `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi Can I get the property for oozie spark action  such that spark job is submitted as "user" not as "YARN"

Comment: This feature is called "impersonation" and as far as I know it is not configurable for action but for whole oozie servers configuration.

Comment: you save my day !

Comment: Nit: "mapred" properties are deprecated since Hadoop V2, and may be ignored in V3 => `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.env`